# Version Incompatibility Microsoft.Graph

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-graph-api

I'm using microsoft.graph to access Teams user data and initiate a call to said user. Afterwards I utilize microsoft.graph.communications.calls (.media) to access media of the ongoing call.

To iniate a call I used this tutorial

https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/graph/api/application-post-calls?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=csharp#http-request

It relies on microsoft.graph.beta. But this is incompatible with .communications.calls (.media) since these rely on v1.0 of microsoft.graph.

I was looking for a solution within v1.0 but the user class doesn't even exist. The link to the tutorial is only a few days old. Can I expect a solution in the following weeks?

Any suggestions a very much appreciated.

Comment: I don't follow. You can call either version with the same token.

Comment: I don't have an issue with getting a token. Maybe I wasn't clear in my description of the problem. 
I'm using the c# api which means I installed the respective nuget packages. Installing microsoft.graph.communications.calls leads to an installation of microsoft.grpah v1.0 due to dependencies. But there is no user class in v1.0 which is more or less essential in the task at hand.

Thanks a lot for looking at my problem!

Answer (score 0):

When you're using the [Microsoft Graph Communications SDK](https://microsoftgraph.github.io/microsoft-graph-comms-samples/) you need to allow the SDK to handle the calls for you. The core purpose of this SDK is to have it automatically route calls to either the v1.0 or Beta versions based on the endpoint your calling.

From the [documentation:](https://microsoftgraph.github.io/microsoft-graph-comms-samples/docs/articles/index.html#graph-communications-sdk-and-client-builder)

> The `ICommunicationsClient` object is the entry point to the Graph Communications SDK and the Calling SDK. This SDK is designed for stateful services and provides additional support on top of the Graph Core SDK for resource state management and media management. The `ICommunicationsClientBuilder` is the object used to construct a new `ICommunicationsClient` with the desired settings.